# How to handle transitions of custom elements generated by an event?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm wondering what the appropriate way is to deal with custom elements generated using on('renderlet', function(){...}) when you need them to transition smoothly? Any help would be great

Comment: changed my answer to a happier one - please try again

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible, as of dc.js 2.0.0 beta 11, to add elements in the 'pretransition' event, and at the same time add transitions on these elements.

The transitions will run in parallel with the transitions on built-in elements.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/806

```
chart.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
    chart.select(...).append(...)
       // create stuff
       .transition().duration(chart.transitionDuration())
       // change stuff
```