# dc.js : how to change circle color on mouseover

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm trying to highlight the color of the circle in my time series chart built using dc.js. I've found few solutions online where they mention about SelectAll() method. But it will select all the circles and not the specific one where I do mouseover.

```
 chart.selectAll("circle")
      .style("fill", "orange")
```

Can someone please help on how to apply color to the circle where I do mouseover in dc.js

Comment: Show fill your code.

Comment: Not familiar with dc.js, but have you tried just using a plain CSS directive? Something like this `#chart circle:hover {fill: orange;}` inside your <style> element should work... unless overridden by the library or other styles.

Comment: please use the [dc.js] tag for questions related to the charting library - [dc] is quite something else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `this` keyword to refer to the circle you are hovering on.
I've created a simple fiddle to get you started.

```js
var chart = d3.select('#chart')
  .style('fill', 'orange')

chart.selectAll('circle').on('mouseover', function() {
  d3.select(this).attr('fill', '#00c')
}).on('mouseout', function() {
  d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'orange')
})
```

```html
<link href="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.15/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id='chart' height="100" width="400">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"  />
  <circle cx="80" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"  />
  <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"  />
  <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"  />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the syntax doesn't seem to be working in dc.js. Can you please suggest a similar syntax for dc.js?

Comment: @user3754877 Are you getting any errors? Can you provide a working example?

Comment: You'd have to do this after rendering. Or better, put it inside `chart.on('pretransition', function() { ... })`

Comment: Here's a better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674385/how-to-handle-transitions-of-custom-elements-generated-by-an-event

Thanks @Gordon :)

Comment: @ Aditya K, please find below the working example where I need to incorporate the mouse-over color change feature. Please help me with the change. I tried applying the suggestions given by you and Gordon but nothing seems to working.    http://jsfiddle.net/cp4dpfry/9/